# How to disable default qpushbutton

Tags: qt

I created `qpushbuttons` with `qtdesigner` and as a default I want to make them disabled without clicking them in other words before the dialog screen comes they should already have been disabled.I ask that because I write a cinema seat reservation and when somebody buy the seat I make it disabled and the color red but after closing and re-running the program they disappear and they turn to default. I want to do is; when I re-run the program they should be seen disabled and color red. How can I do that. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to disable the button or just disable all buttons from being the default when the enter key is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that from *QtDesigner*, the advantage being you don't need to code anything.

Select your `QPushButton`, and make sure the `enabled` property is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `yourDialog->show()`, execute `yourDialog->yourPushButton->setDisabled()`.

Comment: we should only change like this yourDialog.yourPushButton->setDisabled()   yourDialog.yourPushButton->isEnabled(false)